# Sonata Admin Bundle translation

Tags: symfony, translation, sonata-admin

I am setting translation of sonataadminbundle according this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/translation.html)

I have done like this

made
Acme/AdminBundle/Resources/translations/messages.ja.yml

```
form:
    name: 名前
```

in Acme/Adminbundle/Admin/ImgAdmin.php

```
class ImgAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $translationDomain = 'messages';

   public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')     
            ->add('name',null,array('label'=> 'form.name'))
```

in config.yml

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: ja }
```

then I have cache cleared.

However translation doesn't work.

Is there anything I have to do??

Answer (score 0):

Did you empty the cache with the command line tool? I've found that I need to empty the cache completely with `rm -rf app/cache/*` (or the specific environments) for new translations to show up as expected.

Comment: I have done the cache clear manually, but in vain. thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not looking for an answer anymore, but just for reference: I just had the same issue and noticed that in `config.yml`, I still had somewhere:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
```

So in your case, it could still be looking for a `messages.en.yml` that doesn't exist.